# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lconfig++

Tags: linux, gcc, g++

I assume this is a common question but I think I have tried what I could.
When I try to compile this file:

`g++ -o build/opt/fftoggle --static build/opt/fftoggle.o build/opt/config.o build/opt/galloc.o build/opt/log.o build/opt/pin_cmd.o -lconfig++ -lpthread`

I get `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lconfig++`

I assume this is related to libconfig++ library which I find it to be in `/usr/lib64/libconfig++.so` by running `ld -lconfig++ --verbose`

This is what I get when I run `ld -lconfig++ --verbose`

```
attempt to open //usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib64/libconfig++.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib64/libconfig++.so succeeded
-lconfig++ (//usr/lib64/libconfig++.so)
libstdc++.so.6 needed by //usr/lib64/libconfig++.so
found libstdc++.so.6 at /usr/local/lib64//libstdc++.so.6
libm.so.6 needed by //usr/lib64/libconfig++.so
found libm.so.6 at /usr/lib64/libm.so.6
libc.so.6 needed by //usr/lib64/libconfig++.so
found libc.so.6 at /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
libgcc_s.so.1 needed by //usr/lib64/libconfig++.so
found libgcc_s.so.1 at /usr/local/lib64//libgcc_s.so.1
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 needed by /usr/local/lib64//libstdc++.so.6
found ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 at /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
```

Now, My `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` already has `/usr/lib64/` in its path but still I face this issue and on top of this, I tried to compile by linking the library in the compile command too:

`g++ -o build/opt/fftoggle --static build/opt/fftoggle.o build/opt/config.o build/opt/galloc.o build/opt/log.o build/opt/pin_cmd.o -L/usr/lib64/ -lconfig++ -lpthread`

Still no luck. Am I missing something or is `-lconfig++` not related to `libconfig++`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is you need a static library and don't have one.

> g++ -o build/opt/fftoggle --static

I'm not sure why that works; the option is `-static` (one dash). **info gcc** says `-static` *prevents linking with the* [sic] *shared libraries*.  **ld** is telling you there is no such:

> `attempt to open //usr/x86_64-redhat-linux/lib64/libconfig++.a failed`

BTW,

> My LD_LIBRARY_PATH already has /usr/lib64/

LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not used by the static linker.  It influences how the *runtime* linker searches for dynamic libraries when loading executables.

Comment: Okay, removing 'static' flag seems to be working but I wonder what static library do I use to compile it statically. Any suggestions?

Comment: The static library would be named `libconfig++.a`.  Possibly your package manager separates the dynamic from the static versions into two packages.